# Почему не сохраняется знчение переменной, заданное в case?

Tags: php, switch

Инструкция в `default` не выполняется, как я понял, значение переменной `step_1` попросту не видят другие блоки `case`.
Как можно это исправить?

```
if ($sql_isRegistered['registered']!=1) {
      switch (getMessageText()) {
        case 'Привет':
          $message = 'Привет';
          sendMessage($message, $user_id, $token);
          break;
        case 'Шаг2':
          $message = 'Шаг2';
          sendMessage($message, $user_id, $token);
          $step_1 = 1;
          break;

        default:
          if ($step_1 == 1) {
            $info = getMessageText();
            $step_1 = 0;
            $message = 'Отлично! Теперь шаг 3!';
            sendMessage($message, $user_id, $token);
          }
          break;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Вынесите код из под `default:` за пределы `switch`

Comment: @rjhdby увы, тогда два сообщения выводятся подряд, без ожидания ввода пользователем

Answer (score 0):

Принцип работы `switch` в том, что он получил на вход значение, нашел нужный `case` (либо `default`, если он есть) и завершил работу. Если требуется повторное выполнение, то `switch` нужно заворачивать в цикл.